# Error working with two frameworks in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, protocol-buffers

I need to work with two third party frameworks in my Xcode project but the two of them use Google's Protocol Buffer library and they were compiled against different versions of that library. Both frameworks work fine separately but when I try to use them in the same project I get this error message:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL /Users/jari/dev/indooratlas-sdk/indooratlas-ios-sdk/target/framework/IDAAlgorithm/cpp-algorithms/cpp/protobuf/protobuf-cmake/protobuf-2.6.0/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:72] This program was compiled against version 2.4.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (2.6.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "".)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: This program was compiled against version 2.4.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (2.6.0).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "".)
```

The error message states that I should contact the program author to get an update but I would like to know if there is something that I can do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the source code for the frameworks, you should be able to compile them both using the latest version of Protobufs. You will need to regenerate all of the `.pb2.cc` and `.pb2.h` files using the latest `protoc` and link against the latest library version.

If you do not have the source code for the frameworks, then you need to contact the authors and ask them to compile against the newer Protobufs. Without code there is no way to do this yourself.